# What is the correct way to add '.indexOn' rule in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read about the importance of `.indexOn` rule for both performance and pricing (reducing the total of downloaded bytes) and I'm wondering what is the correct way to implement it.

In my case, I have a firebase realtime database at this path `Cosmetics/Outfits`, so I should declare the rule like this:

```
"Cosmetics": {
"Outfits": {
  ".indexOn": ["rarity"]
}}
```

or like this:

```
"Outfits": {
  ".indexOn": ["rarity"]
}
```

In both cases, I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your database schema looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Cosmetics
         |
         --- Outfits
               |
               --- outfitIdOne
               |     |
               |     --- rarity: "rare"
               |
               --- outfitIdTwo
                     |
                     --- rarity: "rare"
```

So every `Outfit` object exist under the `Outfits` node, the rules should look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Cosmetics": {
      "Outfits": {
        ".indexOn": "rarity"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't create the correct index, the server sends all data to the client, place where the filtering takes place. For more information please see the official documentation regarding [indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Comment: Yes, my database schema looks like that. Thank you!
Also, I have another question about pricing because I have read some "horror" stories about unexpected charges.

Let's say my database is `~700kb`. So if a user downloads the whole database it means that I would be charged for `700kb` (neglecting SSL encryption and other connectivity stuff)?

Comment: When you attach a listener on a specific location in Firebase Realtime Database, you are getting all the data that exists within that node, including all subnodes. That being said,, is recommended attaching the listener on the right (lower) level in your tree.