# Firebase Realtime Get Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project via Android Studio and I need to get data from Firebase Realtime Database.

```
public static void uploadData(String username, Measurement measurement) {

        String date = measurement.getDayTime();
        double pulse= measurement.getPulse();
        double step= measurement.getStep();
        double bodyTemp= measurement.getBodyTemp();
        double humidity= measurement.getHumidity();

        Query upload = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

        upload.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    reference.child(username).child(date).child("pulse").setValue(pulse);
                    reference.child(username).child(date).child("step").setValue(step);
                    reference.child(username).child(date).child("bodyTemp").setValue(bodyTemp);
                    reference.child(username).child(date).child("humidity").setValue(humidity);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Via uploadData, I put it to DB:

```
   public static Measurement downloadData(String username){

        //public static DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("healthData");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    String dateStr = "04-09-2021 09:42";
                    tempMeasurement = snapshot.child(username).child(dateStr).getValue(Measurement.class);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });

        return tempMeasurement;
    }
```

But when I want to get data back, it returns me null.

This is how I was trying to write and get a null error:

```
        reportTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Measurement temp = Measurement.downloadData(username);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulse: " + temp.getPulse(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Firebase Json Format

```
    {
"healthData" : {
    "mbaykols" : {
      "04-09-2021 09:42" : {
        "bodyTemp" : 36.5,
        "humidity" : 60,
        "pulse" : 70,
        "step" : 1300
      },
      "04-09-2021 09:43" : {
        "bodyTemp" : 36.5,
        "humidity" : 60,
        "pulse" : 70,
        "step" : 1300
      },
      "04-09-2021 09:45" : {
        "bodyTemp" : 36.5,
        "humidity" : 60,
        "pulse" : 70,
        "step" : 1300
      }
    }
```

Basically, I need to get data. Firstly I was trying to get one by one. After that, I will get the last 5 or 10. What I need is how to reach this child.

## UPDATE 1

What I did on Rules is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1632776400000",  // 2021-9-28
    ".write": "now < 1632776400000",  // 2021-9-28

    "healthData":{
      "username":{
        ".indexOn": ["date","pulse","step","bodyTemp","humidity"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## UPDATE 2

```
             DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
             DatabaseReference mbaykolsRef = rootRef.child("healthData").child(username);
             Query queryByName = mbaykolsRef;
             queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {

                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                             String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                             long pulse = ds.child("pulse").getValue(long.class);
                             long step = ds.child("step").getValue(long.class);
                             long bodyTemp = ds.child("bodyTemp").getValue(long.class);
                             long humidity = ds.child("humidity").getValue(long.class);
                             Log.d("TAG", date + "/" + pulse + "/" + step + "/" + bodyTemp + "/" + humidity);
                         }
                     } else {
                         Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                     }

                 }
             });
```

**It worked. I guess, it is about databaseReference and query definition. I changed them as you see and get type error. After converting String to long type, now I can reach data**

Logcat output:

```
2021-09-04 18:31:59.097 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 11:07:47/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.099 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 11:07:52/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.100 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 11:13:34/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.101 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 11:16:27/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.101 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 16:00:36/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.102 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 17:07:31/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.103 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 17:13:30/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.103 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 17:32:37/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.104 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 18:03:20/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.104 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 18:03:25/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.107 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 18:23:19/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.108 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 18:23:27/70/1300/36/60
2021-09-04 18:31:59.108 18739-18739/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: 04-09-2021 18:23:51/70/1300/36/60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. There's no need to perform four different `setValue()` operations in order to add four values under the same child:

```
reference.child(username).child(date).child("pulse").setValue(pulse);
reference.child(username).child(date).child("step").setValue(step);
reference.child(username).child(date).child("bodyTemp").setValue(bodyTemp);
reference.child(username).child(date).child("humidity").setValue(humidity);
```

You can simply create a Map<String, Object>:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("pulse", pulse);
data.put("step", step);
data.put("bodyTemp", bodyTemp);
data.put("humidity", humidity);
```

And perform a single operation:

```
reference.child(username).child(date).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

That's more likely to be used, as you can add the data in a single go. When using multiple operations, you might end up having inconsistent data, as one of the operations might fail.

Now, to get the data, you should create a query and attach a listener like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mbaykolsRef = rootRef.child("healthData").child("mbaykols");
Query queryByName = mbaykolsRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String pulse = ds.child("pulse").getValue(String.class);
                String step = ds.child("step").getValue(String.class);
                String bodyTemp = ds.child("bodyTemp").getValue(String.class);
                String humidity = ds.child("humidity").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", pulse + "/" + step + "/" + bodyTemp + "/" + humidity);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
70/1300/36.5/60
70/1300/36.5/60
70/1300/36.5/60
```

If you want to limit the result, simply add a `limit(5)` call.

Comment: ```2021-09-04 17:38:32.258 17116-17165/com.example.bitirme I/RepoOperation: get for query /healthData/mbaykols falling back to disk cache after error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "username", for path "/healthData/mbaykols", to the rules
2021-09-04 17:38:32.259 17116-17116/com.example.bitirme D/TAG: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "username", for path "/healthData/mbaykols", to the rules```

Comment: [Give it a try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database) and tell me if it works.

Comment: I tried something, but I'm not sure. The error that I get is gone, but still cant see anything on Logcat

Comment: Is the onComplete even triggered? If you are using `Log.d("TAG", ds.toString());`, is something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I made it. Thank you for helping

Comment: Basically, I tried to mentioned it on UPDATE2.