# How can I get the username by search using the phone number in firebase realtime databse?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to search by the phone number and get the parent key "Sajeeb" or the username using Java. Currently, I am taking the phone number as input and getting all keys and values of the "user" child.

Security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

[image: I want to search by this phone number to get the username]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Sajeeb" is the key of the node, you can simply get it using a call to ".getKey()". So please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query queryByPhone = usersRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo("+8801413565895");
queryByPhone.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String userName = ds.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", userName);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
String userName = ds.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
```

To get the value of the "userName" field. Both solutions will work and will produce the following output in the logcat:

```
Sajeeb
```

Comment: unfortunately, not working. Getting the exception output

Comment: "unfortunately, not working" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What is the exact exception the you get? Please also edit the question and show us what's the exact code you are using.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it.
I am getting "Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "phone", for path "/users", to the rules"
this exeption

Comment: [Give it a try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database) and tell me if it works.

Comment: Working after adding the indexOn rule

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work and you're very welcome, Sajeeb.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `orderByChild` with `equalTo`  to get that user's node only:

```
String myUserId = getUid();

Query myUserQuery = databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("phone").equalTo(PHONE_NUMBER);

myUserQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

Try setting the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      ".indexOn": ["phone"]
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that your current rules allow anyone to read/write to database so you might want to rewrite those. For this issue, you just need to add `indexOn` as shown above.

Comment: No luck.

java.lang.Exception: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "phone", for path "/users", to the rules
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1.onResponse(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:427)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$8.onResponse(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1325)
        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:518)

Comment: @SajeebShahriar you would have to add that in security rules. Can you please update your question with the security rules?

Comment: Done. Rules added. Please check

Comment: @SajeebShahriar try copying rules from my answer. You replace existing rules with it.