# Get Value From Realtime Firebase Inside Child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Greeting everyone, im working a project right now and need help for firebase realtime database.

> My firebase Project

[image]
As you guys can see in the above picture, inside student, I have matric number, and inside matric number have block and department.

I have a barcode scanner which scan the value of department and return to get the matric number. Any solution.

Below code is my progress.

```
mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    r = result.getText();
                    Query s = ref.equalTo("JTMK", "department");
                    name.setText(r);
        }});}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the matric number of the student, indeed a query is required. Assuming that `result.getText()` returns `JTMK`, please use the following lines of code:

```
mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
        String department = result.getText();
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference studentRef = db.child("Student");
        Query queryByDepartment = studentRef.orderByChild("department").equalTo(department).limitToFirst(1);
        queryByDepartment.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                        String block = ds.child("block").getValue(String.class);
                        name.setText(block);
                        Log.d("TAG", block);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

1. There is no need to use `runOnUiThread` when reading data from the Realtime Database.
2. Firebase API is asynchronous. So I recommend you read the following resource:

   - [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)
3. When you run the code, you should see in the logcat `BESTARI 4`, which will also be set to `name` TextView.

Comment: i have try your answer but i got `D/TAG: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "department", for path "/Student", to the rules`

Comment: So have you tried to add the index that is specified in the error message? If not, try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database) out. Does it work now after creating the index?