# Retrieve count data from Firebase Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to count the number of children in my DB table that meet a certain condition. If the `isSeen` column equals `false` then I want to count that, if it equals `true` I don't want to count it.

Currently, it's not working but if I change the query from `Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true);` to `Query query =  usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen");` I get a number but it's not the correct way. Can someone please help me?

Rules:

```
{   
"rules": {     
  ".read": true,     
    ".write": true,     
      "Messages": {        
          ".indexOn": "isSeen"       
       }     
  }   
} 

"Messages": {
"b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93": {
  "DIt5bGqw2WS4eGHNqQJKxZSn3B72": {
    "-N8NCgnwX6V7ghfGlcWS": {
      "dateAdded": 1659337356887,
      "date_time": "Aug-01-2022 3:02:36 AM",
      "from": "DIt5bGqw2WS4eGHNqQJKxZSn3B72",
      "isSeen": true,
      "message": "Yoo",
      "to": "b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "-N99iQjlMfeyOM_VCAEB": {
      "dateAdded": 1660184797462,
      "date_time": "Aug-10-2022 10:26:37 PM",
      "from": "DIt5bGqw2WS4eGHNqQJKxZSn3B72",
      "isSeen": true,
      "message": "Wassup",
      "to": "b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93",
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
},
```

---

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
    Query query = usersRef.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true);
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                long count = task.getResult().getChildrenCount();
                Log.d("TAG1", "count: " + count);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG2", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
```

Error message:

```
D/TAG2: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "isSeen", for path "/Messages/b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93", to the rules
```

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Id6e.png)

Comment: Does your `isSeen` value a boolean? or a string? if the values stored in `isSeen` is a string then you need to use a string value instead of a boolean. `.equalTo("true")`

Comment: It's a boolean @MarcAnthonyB

Comment: Do you have any record that has the value of  `isSeen` set to true? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: No its all false @AlexMamo

Comment: If all are false how do you expect to get results? I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexMamo It's a messaging system. I'm trying to get the number of messages the user has not seen yet and show it as a notification badge. If `isSeen` is false, then I want to count that as apart of the notifications. If it's true then I don't want to count it because the user already saw that message.

Comment: @AlexMamo whenever I add `.equalTo` to this line `Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo("true");` I don't see any results. But if I remove it, then I see results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using the following query:

```
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true);
```

Firebase will always return the exact data you are querying, meaning that you'll get all elements that have the `isSeen` field set to `true`. Please note that there is no way you can query by a negation. So something like this is **not** possible:

```
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").notEqualTo(true);
//
```

According to your comment in which you say that you don't have any elements where the `isSeen` field is set to `true`, then your query will yield no results, and that's the expected behavior.

While @TimothyPham's answer will work, using `getChildrenCount()` might be the best solution. Why? Because if you have a lot of messages this operation requires you to read all of them in order to provide a number. The best solution I can think of would be to increment/decrement a counter as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to save users score in firebase and retrieve it in real-time in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)

**Edit:**

```
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            long count = task.getResult().getChildrenCount();
            Log.d("TAG", "count: " + count);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

But this code will only work if you have elements in the database that have he `isSeen` field is set to `true`.

Comment: I've been trying @TimothyPham's answer all day and still nothing.

Comment: Try also my approach. Does it return the number of children where the `isSeen` field is set to `true`?

Comment: This `get()` on the add listener line doesn't work for me. I saw it in one of your other answers also and tried it but It didn't work. It shows up red and asks me to rename the reference.

Comment: Maybe I'm using a different version of something.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. You aren't using the latest version. Update it and tell me if it works.

Comment: I just updated my Android Studio to `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2` and i'm still getting the error

Comment: It's not about Android Studio, it's about Firebase dependencies that should be updated in the Gradle files.

Comment: Ok I updated it and the `get()` problem went away but now I have to update the project to min sdk 19 and compile level 31

Comment: Yes, you should do it. Does it work after you update it?

Comment: About 5 more mins it's still updating.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: No i'm getting this message `D/TAG: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "isSeen", for path "/Messages", to the rules`

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Have you tried adding the index? If not, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database) out. Does it work now?

Comment: I added it but it still doesn't work `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Cosmetics": {
      "Outfits": {
        ".indexOn": "rarity"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I forgot to edit it properly

Comment: So is it ok now? Does it work?

Comment: No it still show the message above `{   "rules": {     
  ".read": true,     
    ".write": true,     
      "Messages": {       
        "isSeen": {         
          ".indexOn": "rarity"       }     }   } }`

Comment: Ok it works but the number is still coming back zero when it should be 2

Comment: So you say that now, you have **two** elements that have the `isSeen` field set to `true`, right? Otherwise, you'll won't get results.

Comment: Yeah I set it to true and it showed 0 results. I set it to false and it showed 0 results.

Comment: That code in my should definitely work. Maybe there is anything else you're doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know I checked it over a few times.

Comment: Please edit y our question and add the code you're using **now**, the rules and the database schema if you have changed it.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: It's badly formated. Can you please add a screenshot, or format it properly? I think I what might be.

Comment: The rules schema ?

Comment: Database schema.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: This is the query that you need `Query query = usersRef.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).chil("DIt5bGqw2WS4eGHNqQJKxZSn3B72").orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true);`. There is one child missing. So you need to add it to your reference, right?

Comment: I don't think another child is missing but I tried and I'm getting this error now `Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "isSeen", for path "/Messages/b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93/b3vYlKZFrje0e3wHyBlWIK4ooK93", to the rules`

Comment: Yes, it's missing. You need to have two UIDs in your reference, one of the logged-in user and the other who's chatting with. Yes, in that case, you have to change the rules too. Your issue turns out to be more complex. In the future try to ask separate questions for each issue that you get.

Comment: Ok I got it now. So in the rules schema, there's no way to enter the UIDs instead of automatically ?

Comment: You always need to have all children when you create a reference. So store them properly so it can be used later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this, it working for me. It read your messages for the first time

```
usersRef.orderByChild("isSeen").equalTo(true).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     Log.d("TAG", "Count:" + String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {        
  }
});
```

Comment: The count still comes back as 0 when it should be 2

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "");
```