# I am unable to getValue() from a child in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Android and Firebase. I'm trying to get a String from the Firebase and compare it with the given string.

Now, when I use getValue(), it displays "Cannot resolve method 'getValue' in 'DatabaseReference'"

Here is the structure of my database

[image]

Here the name after the node "user1" will change, so I am refining the database till user1

Every time a new folder is created by the app, a new node is created within user1 with the same structure

Now, I want to compare each string in node "AmazonLink" with the given string

Here is my code

```
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/user1");


else if(databaseReference.child("AmazonLink").getValue().equals(amazonLink.getText()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DatabaseReference#child(String pathString)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#child(java.lang.String)) method, returns an object of type [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference). As you can see, there is no `getValue()` method inside this class. However, [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) class does contain a [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()).

So in order to check the value of a field in the Realtime Database against a particular value, you have to perform a query and attach a lister like this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userOneRef = db.child("Users/user1");
Query query = userOneRef.orderByChild("AmazonLink").equalTo(amazonLink.getText());
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String amazonLink = ds.child("AmazonLink").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", amazonLink);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

See I have used now [DataSnapshot#getValue(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) which indeed allows me to read the value of the field in a String format.

P.S. The above code will work, **only** if `amazonLink.getText()` will return the exact value of the field it exists in the database.

Comment: how can i set this in a if else statement inside  a button click ,  here what im saying https://codeshare.io/0gzxxl

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you want to check in `else if`? Have you tried to only use `if else` and add the code in my solution there? Besides that, does my solution solve your problem?

Comment: can i continue the discussion tomorrow (from my time zone) as I'm into something else right now

Comment: Hey there. Is there everything alright? Have you solved the problem?

Comment: im sorry but i still didnt understand ow will i run this quesry when the onClick is happend

Comment: Add all the code I have provided, inside the onClick method. Have you tried that?

Comment: okay i pasted the exact same link and also the code is in the proper postion , but still it is passing the data to the next fragment which it should not and shuld show a toats

Comment: here is it https://codeshare.io/0gzxxl

Comment: The if statement shouldn't be placed outside the onComplete, but inside it, right after the for loops end. Give it a try and tell me of it works.

Comment: like this https://codeshare.io/0gzxxl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248436/discussion-between-indie-dev-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: idk , im trying to add a breakpoint on the query and trying to debug it but im not understanding whats happening, the debuger navigates between diffrent files that are from the firebase i guess and then i just cant do step into

Comment: In that case, simply add a log statement `Log.d("TAG", "Testing...")`, and see if you get something printed out in the logcat.

Comment: it shows me "Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "AmazonLink", for path "/Users/user1", to the rules" when i click the button

Comment: Fair enough, you should [add an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848233/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-indexon-rule-in-firebase-realtime-database) as it's indicated in the error message. Add it and tell me if the problem is solved.

Comment: Like this https://codeshare.io/0gzxxl?

Comment: Yes, does it work now? Is you onComplete triggered now?

Comment: It's working perfectly now, the only nitpick is that even if the link already exists in the database, it still navigates to the next fragment when you click it.(but atleast it shows the toast) , here it is https://codeshare.io/0gzxxl

Comment: Good to hear that it worked, Indie. If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own MCVE, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Since the problem related to the index is solved, then can I help you with other information regarding the this question?