# Whenever a condition is met, I do not want to navigate between fragments

Tags: java, android, if-statement

> Sorry for the bad title, I wasn't sure how to express the situation,
> so I wrote it this way.

I recently asked a question about firebase [I am unable to getValue() from a child in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73865409/19585404)

I wanted to show a toast whenever the provided string matches a string in the firebase node. However, when I press the button after entering the text, it displays the toast message, which is what I wanted, but I don't want to navigate to the next fragment.

here is my code

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            Query query = userOneRef.orderByChild("AmazonLink").equalTo(amazonLink.getText().toString());
            query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                        String amazonLink = ds.child("AmazonLink").getValue(String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Amazon link already on tracker",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", amazonLink);
                        Log.d("TAG","Testing1");
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(amazonLink.getText().toString())){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty field not allowed!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG","Testing2");

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("TAG","Testing3");
                        Bundle amazonLinkBundle = new Bundle();
                        amazonLinkBundle.putString("passingLink",amazonLink.getText().toString());
                        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("gettingLink",amazonLinkBundle );
                        Fragment fragment = new FinalHome_Fragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(Home_Fragment.class));
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                }
            });





        });
```

Comment: There are 2 Toasts here so I don't know which one you refer to. I'm assuming you are referring to the one within the foreach loop. If when that toast appear you don't want to navigate to a different fragment you'll have to setup a boolean flag prior to the loop and set it's value to e.g false. If toast was shown, set it to true, and after loop check it's value. If it's true, you break the function (i.e - retrurn;) and if false continues regularly

Comment: can you give me some exacmple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this is the part you are referring to:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                        String amazonLink = ds.child("AmazonLink").getValue(String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Amazon link already on tracker",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", amazonLink);
                        Log.d("TAG","Testing1");
                    }
```

I'd change it to:

```
boolean isFound = false;
for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                        String amazonLink = ds.child("AmazonLink").getValue(String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Amazon link already on tracker",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", amazonLink);
                        Log.d("TAG","Testing1");
isFound = true;
                    }
if(isFound)
     return;
```

something of the sort of this, if that is what you were missing

Comment: can you explain what have you done , becuase looking at the bolean i didnt understand how its stoped navigating to the next fragment, just tell me about the bollean

Comment: I've defined a boolean flag that will give an indication if I have found the required value that prevents the toast message (by calling boolean isFound = false). If you have values inside the task.getResult().getChildren, which I assume means you don't want to navigate to the fragment, I'm setting the flag to true meaning I've found the needed value. Once the foreach loop is done I'm checking the value of the boolean flag and if it's true it means I don't want to show the Toast message and thus I return the function You could also add the check I did to the else (but invert it) for same result